# Can git pre-receive hooks evaluate the incoming commit?

Tags: git, bash, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to write a server side pre-receive git hook to evaluate commits as they are being pushed.

According to the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491942/how-can-you-block-git-commits-from-invalid-users), this should easily be possible by searching git log and filtering out what I want with 'format:'.

I've created the following pre-commit script.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x #for debugging, TODO: remove
echo "parameters are" $@
echo "1 is " $1

#List of banned users
bannedusers=( root )

author_name=$(git show --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%an | head -n1)
author_email=$(git show --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%ae | head -n1)

committer_name=$(git show --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%cn | head -n1)
committer_email=$(git show --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%ce | head -n1)

commit_users=( "${author_name}" "${committer_name}" )


  for acommituser in "${commit_users[@]}"
  do
    :
    echo $acommituser #for debugging, TODO: remove
    for abanneduser in "${bannedusers[@]}"
    do
      :
        echo $abanneduser #for debugging, TODO: remove
        if [[ $abanneduser == $acommituser ]]; then
         echo "################################################################"
         echo "Commits from $abanneduser are not allowed"
         echo "git config user.name bob builder --replace-all"
         echo "git config user.email bob@aol.com"
         echo "git commit --amend --reset-author"
         echo "################################################################"
         exit 1
        fi
    done
  done
```

I find that when I run `git show` or `git log` on the server, the results are for the *current* HEAD, whereas I want to query the *incoming* commit.

How could I modify this script to run `git log` or `git show` on the 'not-yet-recieved' commit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Note: see also [Understanding git rev-list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64397278/1256452), to understand how the code below works.)

You need to use the SHA-1 IDs being supplied on standard input:

```
while read oldsha newsha refname; do
    ... testing code goes here ...
done
```

The "testing code" then needs to look at *at least some* and maybe *all three* items, depending on the tests to be performed.

The value in `$oldsha` will be 40 `0`s if the reference name `$refname` is being proposed to be created.  That is, `$refname` (typically something like `refs/heads/master` or `refs/tags/v1.2`, but any name in `refs/` can appear: `refs/notes/commits`, for instance) does not exist now in the receiving repository, but will exist and will point to `$newsha` if you allow the change.

The value in `$newsha` will be 40 `0`s if the reference name `$refname` is being proposed to be deleted.  That is, `$refname` does exist now and points to object `$oldsha`; if you allow the change, that reference-name will be deleted.

The values of both will be nonzero if the reference name `$refname` is being proposed to be updated, i.e., it currently points to git object `$oldsha`, and if you allow the change, it will point to new object `$newsha` instead.

---

If you just run `git log` or `git show`, git uses the SHA-1 it finds by running `git rev-parse HEAD`.  In a typical receiving repository, `HEAD` is a symbolic reference pointing to `refs/heads/master` (the file `HEAD` literally contains the string `ref: refs/heads/master`), so you will see the top-most commit on branch `master` (as you observed).

You need to look specifically at any new objects coming in.  How do you know which new objects are coming in?  That depends on what's happening to the supplied `$refname`, and possibly *other* refnames as well.

If the refname is to be deleted, nothing new is coming in.  Whether any underlying git *objects* will be deleted (garbage collected) depends on whether that refname is the "last" reference to those objects.  For instance, suppose the entire standard input sequence consists of two directives:

- delete `refs/heads/foo`
- delete `refs/tags/v1.1`

Suppose further that `refs/heads/foo` (branch `foo`) points to commit `F` in this commit-graph diagram, and tag `v1.1` points to annotated tag `G`:

```
A - B - C - D   <-- refs/heads/master
      \
        E - F   <-- refs/heads/foo
             \
              G <-- refs/tags/v1.1
```

Deleting branch `foo` is "safe" in that no commits will go away because annotated tag `G` will retain them, via the `v1.1` tag.

Deleting tag `v1.1` is "safe"(ish) in that no commits will go away because branch `foo` will retain them, via the `refs/heads/foo` reference.  (The annotated tag object itself will go away. It's up to you whether to allow this)

However, deleting *both* is *not* safe: commits `E` and `F` will become unreachable and will be collected.  (It's up to you whether to allow this anyway.)

On the other hand, it's possible that along with those two directives, stdin contains a third directive:

- create `refs/heads/foo2` pointing to commit `H`, with commit `H` pointing to commit `G` as its parent [**Edit: on re-reading this now, I notice the glaring assumption that `G` is a commit object rather than a tag object.  If we assume `G` is a commit object the rest of the below is correct, but the above becomes at least a little wrong.  However, the general idea—that the DAG is protected by having external references—is still right, and this should mostly make sense.**]

in which case deletion of `foo` is safe after all, as the new branch `foo2` will retain commit `H` which will retain commit `G`.

Doing a complete analysis is tricky; it's often better to just do a piecewise analysis that allows "safe" operations (whatever you decide these are), and force users to push updates piecewise in a "safe" manner (create branch `foo2` first, and only then delete branch `foo` as a separate push, for instance).

---

If you only want to look at *new* commits, then, for each reference update:

- If it's a delete, allow it (or use other rules).
- If it's a create or a modification, find commit objects it makes reachable that were not reachable before, and examine those commits.

In most "normal" pre-receive hooks you'd use the methods outlined below, but we have an alternative for this particular task.

---

There's a short-cut method for modifications that handles the most common, and usually most interesting, cases.  Suppose someone proposes updating `refs/heads/foo` from `1234567...` to `9876543...`.  It's possible that some objects in the range already existed, e.g., perhaps `1234567` is the ID of commit `C` and `9876543` is the ID of commit `E`:

```
A - B - C           <-- refs/heads/foo
          \
            D - E   <-- refs/heads/bar
```

in which case this will examine objects D and E.  This is also true if commits `D` and `E` have just been uploaded but have *no* references yet, i.e., the proposed update is to add `D` and `E` and the graph currently looks like this:

```
A - B - C           <-- refs/heads/foo
          \
            D - E   [no reference yet]
```

In either case, a simple:

```
git rev-list $oldsha..$newsha
```

produces the object IDs you should look at.

For new references, there's no short-cut.  For instance, suppose we have the same five commits shown above, with the same `refs/heads/foo` but no `refs/heads/bar`, and the actual proposal is "create `refs/heads/bar` pointing to `E`".  In this case, we should again look at commits `D` and `E`, but there's no obvious way to know about `D`.

The non-obvious way, which only works in some cases, is to find objects that will be reachable given the proposed creation, that are not currently reachable at all:

```
git rev-list $newsha --not --all
```

In this particular case, this will again produce the IDs for `D` and `E`.

---

Now let's consider your particular case, where you want to look at all commits that are being proposed-to-be-added.  Here's a way to handle this one.

For all proposed updates:

- If this one is a delete, we have some deletes.
- If this one is a create or update, we have some new commits; accumulate the new SHA.

If we have some deletes *and* we have accumulated some SHAs, reject the attempt: it's too hard.  Make the user separate out the operations.

Otherwise, if we have no accumulated SHAs, we must just have deletes (or maybe nothing at all—should not happen, but harmless); allow this (exit 0).

Otherwise we must have some new SHA-1 values.

Using the proposed new SHAs as starting points, find all git objects that would be reachable, excluding all objects that are currently reachable under any name.  These are all the new objects.

For each one that is a commit, examine it to see if it's forbidden.  If so, reject the entire operation (even if some parts could succeed); as before, it's too hard to figure out, so make the user separate out the "good" operations from the "bad" ones.

If we get this far, everything is OK; permit the entire update.

In code form:

```
#! /bin/sh
# (untested)
NULL_SHA1="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" # 40 0's
new_list=
any_deleted=false
while read oldsha newsha refname; do
    case $oldsha,$newsha in
    *,$NULL_SHA1) # it's a delete
        any_deleted=true;;
    $NULL_SHA1,*) # it's a create
        new_list="$new_list $newsha";;
    *,*) # it's an update
        new_list="$new_list $newsha";;
    esac
done
$any_deleted && [ -n "$new_list" ] && {
    echo 'error: you are deleting some refs and creating/updating others'
    echo 'please split your push into separate operations'
    exit 1
}
[ -z "$new_list" ] && exit 0

# look at all new objects, and verify them
# let's write the verifier function, including a check_banned function...
check_banned() {
    if [ "$1" = root ]; then
        echo "################################################################"
        echo "Commits from $1 are not allowed"
        echo ... rest of message ...
        exit 1
     fi
}
check_commit() {
    check_banned "$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%an $1)"
    check_banned "$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%cn $1)"
}


git rev-list $new_list --not --all |
while read sha1; do
    objtype=$(git cat-file -t $sha1)
    case $objtype in
    commit) check_commit $sha1;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Perhaps I should open a new question, but where is $oldsha coming from? I added the following debugging to my pre-receive script, all of the following were 0 or null https://gist.github.com/spuder/9795078

Comment: Assuming I did not goof up the script: oldsha should be set by the `while read oldsha newsha refname` line.  So it comes from stdin, as supplied by git when git runs the look.

Comment: I added my code as a gist. The code you provided for me worked perfectly, but I'm mystified how $oldsha $refname and $newsha can all be null, and yet your script still works.

Comment: Hm, where exactly did you add these echo lines?  The old and new SHA-1s and the refname are only valid inside the first "while" loop.  I accumulate each new-sha1 into $new_list, and use that once the loop exits.

Comment: I've updated the gist. I'm guessing that the 3 parameters aren't passed in when the script is executed, but rather are passed in by stdin. Seems very strange git would have been architected that way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes.  The reason is that `git push` can push *many* ref updates all at once.  I can push 400 new branches and 75 tags "simultaneously".

Comment: Thanks again torek, I extended your answer to validate email addresses and check an array of names. I posted it here with attribution, https://github.com/spuder/git-hooks/blob/master/pre-commit

Comment: long answer -- but a very valuable tip is in there: `git rev-list $newsha --not --all`. Brilliant.

Comment: @spuder thanks for your work, I'd like to contribute with another validation logic: validating the commit with the linux user account information. https://github.com/Movidone/git-hooks/blob/master/pre-receive

Comment: @spuder can you please help me understand the use of below command in your github link: `git rev-list $new_list --not --all` : https://github.com/spuder/git-hooks/blob/master/pre-commit#L97

Comment: The `--not --all` trick is not perfect—there are some situations it can't handle (most of which the linked hook rejects earlier)—but it takes care of *the* most common case, and the one most people care about: whenever there are *new* commits that are not reachable from any of the existing branch or tag or other names. That includes both new branch names, and any update to any existing name.

Comment: Remark: `git rev-list $newsha --not --all` will not work in post-receive hook (because then the `$newsha` has already brought its new commits) and you probably want `git rev-list $oldsha..$newsha` instead.