# Get user and commit details in git pre-receive hooks

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I am new to git and git-hooks. I am tryig to validate every push that is made and for that I need two things:-

1. User's details (email-id and name) who made the push
2. Commit messages of all the commits in that push

I need to do that using Git's pre-receive hook, but I am not able to any of the above two mentioned things.

I have been searching this issue on SO, githooks's doc and other sites but nothing worked for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you do not get the name of the person who ran `git push`. You get, instead, the hash IDs of the *proposed updates* to various names (branch names, tag names, and so on). From these hash IDs, you can read the (meta)data in the commits themselves. Because Joe might be pushing commits made by Fred on behalf of Betty, it's important to distinguish author and committer and remember that neither is necessarily the user who invoked `git push`.

Comment: As I mentioned that I am new to this, but yes your point make sense. Thankyou @torek for help, I will surely look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `gitlab` tag in the question, so I assume you've read Gitlab [Server Hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html).

From the [githooks doc on pre-receive](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive), we can see that the hook doesn't take any parameter and it reads ref info from standard input. To read from standard input in bash, you can refer to [the pre-push sample](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample), which you can also find in the local repository's `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` if you haven't specified `init.templateDir` in gitconfig. `pre-receive` uses a different line format from `pre-push`, so modify the `while read` part,

```
#!/bin/bash

# <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
while read oldv newv ref;do
    # get new commits
    newcommits=$(git rev-list ${oldv}..${newv})

    # get committer and email and message of each commit
    for commit in ${newcommits};do
        committer=$(git log -1 ${commit} --pretty="%cn")
        email=$(git log -1 ${commit} --pretty="%ce")
        message=$(git log -1 ${commit} --pretty="%B")
    done
done
```

The above sample misses some checks like if it's a ref creation or deletion like in the `pre-push` sample, and if there's any new commit. It's recommended to add these checks. The hook does not know the pusher's Gitlab account. The committer name and email may not accord with the account.

As `git push` can send one or more given strings to the server by one or more `-o <string>` or `--push-options=<string>` and Gitlab supports the feature, you could also add codes to receive these strings. You can find how to do it in [the pre-receive sample](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-receive.sample).

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay! This works for me
One more thing I want to ask here is, git log is used for the push that are already done so how can we get the details of current push in git log?

Also, can you please share the link where I can get more about these  "cn","ce","B". I have seen these somewhere but different like a, an, b or something

Thanks for help buddy!!

Comment: @learning_bunny: the `%` escapes for `git log` are found in [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), under the section titled **PRETTY FORMATS**.

Comment: This only works for a ref update, and will not work for a ref creation (or deletion), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547375/4669135) for the general case.